# WP Simple Membership - How to display Error message for not registered users?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, plugins

I need help with the Wordpress plugin - WP Simple Membership (https://simple-membership-plugin.com).

I have a problem to display the Message when a user try to login but is not registered. I can see it in my source code, this snippet:

```
<!--
        <div class="swpm-forgot-pass-link">
            <a id="forgot_pass" class="swpm-login-form-pw-reset-link"  href="http://lions.giftgruen.com/anmelden/password-reset/">Passwort vergessen?</a>
        </div>
        <div class="swpm-join-us-link">
            <a id="register" class="swpm-login-form-register-link" href="">Noch kein Mitglied? Registriere dich hier! </a>
        </div>
        <div class="swpm-login-action-msg">
            <span class="swpm-login-widget-action-msg">Benutzer unbekannt</span>
        </div>
      -->
```

But it is somehow not displayed. I don't know how to fix that. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

it's commented out, the `<!--` and `-->` are html comment brackets

replace that snippet with:

```
    <div class="swpm-forgot-pass-link">
        <a id="forgot_pass" class="swpm-login-form-pw-reset-link"  href="http://lions.giftgruen.com/anmelden/password-reset/">Passwort vergessen?</a>
    </div>
    <div class="swpm-join-us-link">
        <a id="register" class="swpm-login-form-register-link" href="">Noch kein Mitglied? Registriere dich hier! </a>
    </div>
    <div class="swpm-login-action-msg">
        <span class="swpm-login-widget-action-msg">Benutzer unbekannt</span>
    </div>
```

I don't know if that will fix your problem though,
It's probably meant to be commented out if it was.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. But this is not what i looked for. This code snippet is commented out but not in the HTML. It may seem that Wordpress commented it out, but why i don't know. Thats the problem i have. Maybe because of 2 other sub-plugins of simple WP membership that I installed. I don't know.